# cv.rectangle showing in wrong position

Tags: python, opencv, multidimensional-array

I'm working on segmentation of facial features using violaJones but suddenly I have a problem with either indexing or the cv.rectangle feature. 
The following code is just a simplification to show the same problem that appeared in my code

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('/Users/david/Desktop/Grimmanet/Images/neutral.jpg')
roi_color = img[212:212+544, 183:183+544]

cv.rectangle(roi_color, (315,132),(108,38), (255, 255, 255), 2)

cv.imshow('img',roi_color)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

roi_color is the portion of img which contains the face, then I calculated that the rectangle given by (315,132,108,38) (x,y,w,h) should be the portion of the eyebrow. But instead, when showing is in a completely different position than the given one.

The rectangle is not positioned at the specified point (315,132).
[image]

I don't really see what the problem could be, even in this simple workflow is still appearing.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I guess, `(315,132),(108,38)` are the coordinates in the original image. So you need to calculate the eye brown in the cropped image.

Comment: They are not, actually even though the rectangle is completely different in width and height to the specified ones. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for [rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle), the signature of the function is

> cv2.rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]])

where `pt1` is one corner of the rectangle (usually top-left) and `pt2` is the corner diagonally across it.

So, to get the shape right, you need

```
width = 108
height = 38
pt1 = (315, 132)
pt2 = (pt1[0] + width, pt1[1] + height)
cv.rectangle(roi_color, pt1, pt2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

The result is

[image: result]

So what happened was `(108,38)`, which is your width and height of your rectangle, was taken to be the second vertex of the rectangle diagonally across `(315, 132)`. This means the function drew the rectangle from the bottom-right corner `(315, 132)` to the top-left corner `(108, 38)`.

Comment: Thanks! that really solve my problem and helped me understand!